# simple loop, 2 indices (SelectionSort algorithm) for sorting an array

Tags: r, loops

i’ve made the following code that unfortunately doesn’t work :

```
#scan the numbers,identify the min ,save it as the first element of
 #the output, repeat 

    Select <- function(n) {
     B <- rep(99,length(n)) #output array, same length as n 
    repeat {
 for (j in 1:length(n)) { 
for (i in 1:length(n)) { 
if (all(n[i]<=n)) {B[j] <- n[i] #if n[i] is the smallest in the #array, save it as B[j] 
n[i] <- Inf } #taking n[i] off the game
 }
 }
 if (all(n==Inf)) {return(B)} #if all are Inf then we're done, else.. #repeat
 } 
}
```

(I tried to be as explainatory as possible) I also added a picture since it's not copied correctly in here : imgur.com/0a3vVO4

thanks in advance !

Comment: So what is your issue? Are there any problems with your algorithm? Errors? I can't identify a question in your post.

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fairly significant issues with your algorithm, code formatting being one of them (please use proper indentation and whitespacing for code readability).

1. I don't think `all` does what you think it does. Have a look at `?all` for some examples.
2. I don't see any swapping happening in your code. Nor do I understand the purpose of `B`.
3. I don't understand the purpose of the `Inf`s. What are they supposed to do?

A straightforward R implementation of the selection sort algorithm from e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/) would lead to

```r
ssort <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
        min_index <- i
        for (j in (i + 1):length(x)) if (x[j] < x[min_index]) min_index = j
        temp <- x[i]
        x[i] <- x[min_index]
        x[min_index] <- temp
    }
    x
}
```

Let's test

```r
set.seed(2020)
x <- round(runif(10, min = 0, max = 10))
identical(sort(x), ssort(x))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: it actually works perfectly, it's just that "all" is not efficient, I should replace it with another logical condition.
also I lacked a break at the end of the first "if" statement

I would like to understand how a "neat" code should look like, could you please help with main guidlines ?
thanks :)

Comment: (1) No, `all` is not the right function here. You want to compare elements (and then swap if necessary).  `all` is a vectorised function acting on a vector; this shouldn't show up in a loop where you step through *elements* of a vector. (2) Defining `B` is unnecessary, and I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `Inf`s. (3) As to "neat code": Take a look at some of the most popular R coding style guides (e.g. [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html).